# Termporary OSX SSL issue NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: macos, ssl, https

[image: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID]

I'm getting a strange network issue on a project I'm working on that seems to effect my computer temporally and then be fine again - it's happened twice in the past month roughly for about 5 minutes. Details are:

I get a network connection issue when the front end tries to connect to the api.

I've tried:

- switching browser (doesn't fix the issue)
- switching wifi networks (doesn't fix the issue)
- switching machines (the site still works fine from my phone or another computer)

After a few minutes the problem resolves itself, I'm pretty confused!

SSL certificate is a PositiveSSL wildcard: https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-wildcard.aspx

Can you think of any reason a problem with our SSL certificate could be causing my computer to temporally block the api?

Answer (score 1):

> self signed ...COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

This cannot be right. It is either self-signed or issued by a trusted CA.

> Can you think of any reason a problem with our SSL certificate could be causing my computer to temporally block the api?

Hickup of server, i.e. configuration change, switch to misconfigured backup server or something like this. Or some firewall in between trying SSL interception. Or some attacker trying man-in-the-middle. Or hickup of DNS server or attack against it so that the wrong IP address gets used. Or ....

It is very hard to tell what's going on without having more information. Especially you need to have a look at the certificate and certificate chain you get back at this moment and compare it to the one you get usually.

Comment: Thanks - I think I was looking at the intermediary certificate, have updated the question with the correct details. Will post more if it reoccurs and I'll get a screengrab of the certificate chain.